# What are the common EventIds MSMQ will log?

Tags: msmq

When I view administrative tools / msmq logging on windows 7, I see envelope information from each of my msmq messages flowing through the system.   They all have EventId = 2.   Nothing out there seems to document if this is a success or a failure condition.  Is EventId 2 a good thing, and has Microsoft documented it somewhere?

Comment: I may just not understand, but can you elaborate what you mean by admin tools / msmq logging? It sounds like you're viewing an event log? But I get confused when you start talking about viewing the envelope information for each messages, like you are talking about the actual message queue, which do not have event id's.

Comment: This is in the windows event log, built into the control panel / administrative tools.  MSMQ generates log entries in it.